# Are junction boxes needed for LED strip light wiring splices?

Tags: lighting, led, junction-box, low-voltage

Are junction boxes required for 24v splicing in the United States?  Are small plastic enclosures sufficient or would you use standard junction boxes for 110v?

The application is a 24v lighting system operating on a trunked design.  Each trunk would power ~85w of LED strips.

- Transformer: 24v 500w 3 circuit output -
  [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01IU8QBCO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IU8QBCO)
- LED strips: 24v @ 4.4w
  per foot - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B014600JN2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014600JN2)

[image]

Comment: These plastic Tee connections would all be surface mounted, There should be no need for an enclosure.

Comment: My concerns would be are you trying to link all the branches to one main trunk line.  Normally the max is two 5 meters or 36' per feed. So you would have a 2-2-1 for your three feeds out of the transformer.

Comment: Currently the system is just bare wire soldered to the LED strips and connected to the trunk with wire nuts. Though i suppose if a barrel-style plug connection is considered safe for 90w of power then that'd be an option.

Comment: I am talking about 10mm Tee LED connectors, which is a much cleaner connection like these [sample tee connections](https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Shape-Strip-Connector-Extension/dp/B07FJMPF6R/ref=sr_1_30?dchild=1&keywords=2+pin+10mm+tee+connectors&qid=1589999191&sr=8-30).  Remember 32'  max length can be connected together on a circuit.  Your strips would look continuous.  They also have the connectors with wire in case you don't want continous light at the Tee

Comment: Those Tee connectors would work great for someone that has the lighting installed continuously.  In my case I'm using it as shop lighting in my garage so i've got it installed as 2' segments spread evenly all throughout the 25' x 25' shop.

Comment: That power supply won't do.  You need to use a power supply that is actually UL-Listed (or CSA or ETL).  That only has the dreaded CE mark (China Export, it's a ripoff of an EU mark).   Proper UL-listed supplies are cheap and common commodities.   The low voltage DC stuff does not need UL/CSA/ETL.

Answer (score 1):

No that voltage is below the safe contact limit threshold the wiring could even be exposed but not recommended.